# Use jQuery to get value inside html tag

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="dragCell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="thirdSlot">
  <input class="appointmentClassId" type="hidden" value="0013E00000DKsxpQAD">
  <input class="appContactClassId" type="hidden" value="0033E00000AeYkQQAV">
  <p>Westbrook Restaurants</p>
  <p>Z1</p>
  <input class="inputHidden-1" name="hiddenName" type="hidden" value="a1M3E0000009rHRUAY">
</div>
<span title="10 AM"></span>
```

I would like to use access the `title` attribute in the `<span>`. i.e `10 AM`. How could I do this?

Comment: Where is your JS code? Under what event are you trying to do this? And on which element?

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said you need put your JS code . For a simple answer I would say user `$('span').attr('title')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Very simple, use jQuery `attr()`:-*

```js
console.log($('span').attr('title'));

console.log($('#thirdSlot > p:eq(1)').text());

console.log($('#thirdSlot > p:eq(1)').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragCell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="thirdSlot">
  <input class="appointmentClassId" type="hidden" value="0013E00000DKsxpQAD">
  <input class="appContactClassId" type="hidden" value="0033E00000AeYkQQAV">
  <p>Westbrook Restaurants</p>
  <p>Z1</p>
  <input class="inputHidden-1" name="hiddenName" type="hidden" value="a1M3E0000009rHRUAY">
</div>
<span title="10 AM"></span>
```

Note:- jquery library needed. So add that in your code like the above example.Thanks

Comment: How would I get the value of the second <p>. I tried nth:child(3).. doesnt work

Comment: @saint  check the answer once again. I had  added that part also

Comment: what in the case I want to get the id dynamically. for instance, the click event could have been on #secondSlot. I wan to get whichever div that was selected and then the p:eq(1)').text() of that. How can i do this??

Comment: never mind. figured out: $j(this).find('p:eq(1)').text()

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].getAttribute("title");
```

now x will be "10 AM"

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log($('span[id="[your id]"]').attr("title"));
```

or

```
console.log($('span.' + [your className] + ']').attr("title"));
```

or

```
console.log($('#thirdSlot').find('span').attr('title'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify id of your span tag

```
<span id="spanid" title="10 AM"></span>
```

Use JQuery code:

```
var v=$('#spanid').attr('title');
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an classname to your span and then use this code:

```
$('span.className').attr('title','New Title');​
```

Comment: He wants to get the value of the span, you are trying to set a new value

Answer (score 1):

I added an `id="titleSpan"` to your span and used jQuery to access its `title` attribute in the onload function. Take a look at the below snippet:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dragCell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="thirdSlot">
  <input class="appointmentClassId" type="hidden" value="0013E00000DKsxpQAD">
  <input class="appContactClassId" type="hidden" value="0033E00000AeYkQQAV">
  <p>Westbrook Restaurants</p>
  <p>Z1</p>
  <input class="inputHidden-1" name="hiddenName" type="hidden" value="a1M3E0000009rHRUAY">
</div>

<span id="titleSpan" title="10 AM"></span>

<script>

  $(function(){
  
    var spanTitle = $("#titleSpan").attr("title");
    console.log(spanTitle);
  
  });

</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`.attr('attributename')` function is Use to get attribute value of Tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dragCell ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="thirdSlot">
  <input class="appointmentClassId" type="hidden" value="0013E00000DKsxpQAD">
  <input class="appContactClassId" type="hidden" value="0033E00000AeYkQQAV">
  <p>Westbrook Restaurants</p>
  <p>Z1</p>
  <input class="inputHidden-1" name="hiddenName" type="hidden" value="a1M3E0000009rHRUAY">
</div>
<span title="10 AM"></span>

<button onclick="console.log($('span').attr('title'))" >Get  Value</button>
```